# VelocityJS 2.0.5 - SkewX

Tags: javascript, velocity.js

Just playing around with VelocityJS 2.0.5

```
    $l1.velocity({
      translateX: ['-50%', -lineWidth],
      translateY: [0, 0],
      width: lineWidth
    }, 300, 'easeInOutCubic');

    $l1.velocity({skewY: ["-9deg", "0deg"]}, 400, 'easeInOutQuart');
```

The above code for some reason doesn't seem to skew the div at all, any ideas? With older versions of velocityJS (1.5.0) it works fine, but with the latest version it does not work.

using transform works but it overrides the translateX and translateY.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is not valid css - Velocity V2 does not provide (broken) shortcuts for the various `transform` properties, please use `transform` directly.

https://github.com/julianshapiro/velocity/blob/master/V2_CHANGES.md